# Image is not displaying on Client Side on Asp,Net IIS Using byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I can render the image in my browser when run my code in visual studio. But when I deploy it in the **IIS** and try to access the site from the client's browser, the image is not displayed anymore and I get an error.

Error:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQND........ net::ERR_INVALID_URL

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddData(QrModel qrModel)
{
    var name = qrModel.Name;
    var mobile = qrModel.Mobile;
    var message = qrModel.Message;

    var encoder = new QRCodeEncoder(); // Starting the QR Creator
    var str = "Name: " + name + "\n"
          + "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n"
          + "Message: " + message;
    var img = encoder.Encode(str);

    var imgByte = ImageToByteArray(img);
    var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte);
    var imageDataUrl = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
    ViewBag.ImageData = imageDataUrl;

    return PartialView();
}

public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and this is my partial view:

```
<table style="overflow:hidden; table-layout:fixed; position:relative; width:100%; border: 1px solid">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="td-center"><img src="@ViewBag.ImageData)" alt="Qr Image"/></td>
        </tr>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I correct this? Thank you.

Comment: which browser are you testing?

Comment: Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera. It all has the same result.